# SwiftUI Speech to Text in Afrikaans

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I have been trying to use SFSpeechRecognizer to record Afrikaans but it is not supported by iOS. Any reference of what else I can do? I have looked everywhere and there is barely any resource on any alternative. I am doing my code on SwiftUI, not Storyboard so any similar reference or guidance would be very helpful. Thank you!

I have used SFSpeechRecognizer and I am writing my code on XCode SwiftUI

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please provide a code snippet you have done so far or some links of articles you have tried before. How your _SFSpeechRecognizer_ is initialized or used in the code?

Comment: If that class doesn’t support a language, you can’t make it support it. Alternatives would be to find an online service that does support it, or spend a couple of mil collecting samples and training your own recognizer.